# How to initiate a Mozilla Browsing session through FirefoxProfile?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am trying to use Firefox Profiling. But it is throwing an error at below line in the code. Please see attached snapshot

Please, can someone assist?

Code : -

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(prof);
```

[image]

Error: -->

> The constructor FirefoxDriver(FirefoxProfile) is undefined

Below versions I am using:-

- Selenium--> 3.12.0
- Firefox Setup 50.0

Codes:

```
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
 import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;
 public class Gmail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");

       ProfilesIni allProf = new ProfilesIni();// all profiles
       FirefoxProfile prof = allProf.getProfile("Abhi_Selenium");

       WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(prof);
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       driver.get("http://gmail.com");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't such constructor that gets the profile and creates the driver. That's what the exception is telling you. You can see the javadoc here:

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html

You can try something like that:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setProfile(yourProfile);
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Comment: Thanks for checking on my issue

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the *Java Docs* of [**`FirefoxDriver`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html) Class in **Selenium Java Client v3.13.0** the valid *constructors* are as follows:

- [**`FirefoxDriver()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html#FirefoxDriver--)
- [**`FirefoxDriver(FirefoxOptions options)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html#FirefoxDriver-org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions-)
- [**`FirefoxDriver(GeckoDriverService service)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html#FirefoxDriver-org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService-)
- [**`FirefoxDriver(GeckoDriverService service, FirefoxOptions options)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html#FirefoxDriver-org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService-org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions-)
- [**`FirefoxDriver(XpiDriverService service)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html#FirefoxDriver-org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService-)
- [**`FirefoxDriver(XpiDriverService service, FirefoxOptions options)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html#FirefoxDriver-org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService-org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions-)

So clearly, as per your code trials the following line of code is not a valid option:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(prof);
```

Hence you see the error as:

```
The constructor FirefoxDriver(FirefoxProfile) is undefined
```

The auto suggestions are as follows:

[image: auto_suggestions]

### Solution

As a solution:

- Either you can convert the instance of `FirefoxProfile` into `DesiredCapabilities()` type object and then `merge()` into an `FirefoxOptions()` type object as follows:

  ```
  ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
  FirefoxProfile testprofile = profile.getProfile("Abhi_Selenium");
  DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
  dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, testprofile);
  FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
  opt.merge(dc);
  WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(opt);
  ```
- Or you can straightaway use the `setProfile()` method through an instance of `FirefoxOptions()` as follows:

  ```
  ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
  FirefoxProfile testprofile = profile.getProfile("Abhi_Selenium");
  FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
  opt.setProfile(testprofile);
  WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(opt);
  ```

**Note**: To use an existing **Firefox Profile** for your *Test Execution* first you have to create a *Firefox Profile* manually following the instructions at [**Creating a new Firefox profile on Windows**](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_a_new_Firefox_profile_on_Windows).

Comment: I guess that's a prettier version of my answer