# Getting error as "NoSuchSessionException" when trying to open an website through FirefoxProfile

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am running the below code, to open a URL. However, I am getting error as "NoSuchSessionException". Kindly suggest.

Is it because of the below versions I am using.

> Selenium--> 3.12.0, Firefox Setup 50.0 and geckodriver-v0.21.0-win64

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;

public class Gmail {

public static void main(String[] args){

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");

FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();  
ProfilesIni allProf = new ProfilesIni();// all profiles
FirefoxProfile prof = allProf.getProfile("Abhi_Selenium");
options.setProfile(prof);

//FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://gmail.com");

}

}
```

Comment: There is something wrong with you `FireFoxProfile` I am assuming. Try without the profile.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51583522/firefox-profiling-throwing-error

Comment: Thanks.. will check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 ways to use a existing *Firefox Profile* to access a *Web Application* as follows:

- Using `DesiredCapabilities()` and `FirefoxOptions()`:

  ```
  public class FirefoxProfile_dc_opt {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
          FirefoxProfile testprofile = profile.getProfile("Abhi_Selenium");
          DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
          dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, testprofile);
          FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
          opt.merge(dc);
          WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(opt);
          driver.get("https://www.google.com");
      }
  }
  ```
- Using `FirefoxOptions()`:

  ```
  public class FirefoxProfile_opt {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
          FirefoxProfile testprofile = profile.getProfile("Abhi_Selenium");
          FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
          opt.setProfile(testprofile);
          WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(opt);
          driver.get("https://www.google.com");
      }
  }
  ```

**Note**: Ensure that you have already created a *Firefox Profile* as **Abhi_Selenium** before you trigger your *Test*.

---

### Update

As you are still seeing the exception as **no such session**, perform the following upgradation/cleanup steps:

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u181**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.13.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [**GeckoDriver v0.20.1**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) level.
- Ensure *GeckoDriver* is present in the specified location.
- Ensure *GeckoDriver* is having executable permission for non-root users.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v61.0.1*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. Please can you let me know what are the versions of Firefox/Selenium and Geckodriver you are using.. I tried using your suggestion and I am still getting the exception of "no such session".. Thanks

Comment: @AbhishekDingre Checkout my answer update and let me know the status

Comment: Thanks!! it was compatibility issue .. with my firefox, geckodriver and selenium versions

Comment: @AbhishekDingre Glad to be able to help you !!! Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **FireFoxProfile** class and **FirefoxOptions** class to set a profile.

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions(); 
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile  = new FirefoxProfile(pathToProfile);
options.setProfile(firefoxProfile);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AbhishekDingre : well , if that works , you can simply accept this answer , by clicking on check mark which is just under the down vote button.

Answer (score 0):

On the first look the path to firefox.exe is missing. There is my setup:

```
public class foo{
    private static WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();         
        FirefoxProfile selenium_profile = allProfiles.getProfile("selenium_profile");
        options.setProfile(selenium_profile);
        options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\pburgr\\Desktop\\geckodriver-v0.20.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();}

// @Before, @After, @AfterClass and @Test

}
```